# Problems installing Oracle Database 11 on solaris 11.3

Tags: oracle-11g, solaris-11, sparc

i'm trying to install Oracle Database on Solaris 11.3 and i'm getting the following error:

```
 INFO: /usr/ccs/bin/make -f /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/ins_precomp.mk relink EXENAME=proc

INFO: Linking /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/proc

INFO: ld: warning: file libucrypto.so.1: required by /usr/lib/sparcv9/libnsl.so, not found

INFO: Undefined                 first referenced
 symbol                             in file
MD5Init                             /usr/lib/sparcv9/libnsl.so

INFO: MD5Final                            /usr/lib/sparcv9/libnsl.so

INFO: MD5Update                           /usr/lib/sparcv9/libnsl.so

INFO: ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors

INFO: make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/proc'
Current working directory /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib

INFO: *** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
echo "Linking /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/proc"; \
rm -f /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/proc; \
     /usr/ccs/bin/ld -o /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/proc -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/ -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/ -dy /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/prod/lib/v9/crti.o /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/prod/lib/v9/crt1.o /
```

As i can't tell the libnsl.so is not well linked to the libucrypto.so.1 library, this is the ldd output for the library:

```
root@hdv-snr-bta-10:~# ldd /usr/lib/sparcv9/libnsl.so
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/64/libmp.so.2
        libucrypto.so.1 =>       /lib/64/libucrypto.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libc.so.1
        libelf.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libelf.so.1
        libcryptoutil.so.1 =>    /lib/64/libcryptoutil.so.1
        libz.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libz.so.1
```

My OS is solaris 11.3 Sparc,

```
root@hdv-snr-bta-10:~# uname -a 
SunOS hdv-snr-bta-10 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

there is a bug in Oracle Solaris 11.3 so you must  download the latest SRU and install it in order to fix the libraries linking problem.

Answer (score -2):

install openssl using this link 
https://www.openssl.org/

and copy libucrypto in desire place.
YOUR PROBLEM WILL SOLVE.

Comment: Installing openSSL from source is not necessarily the best approach, all the more so if the asker was hoping to have their install supported. Solaris is still receiving [updates to openSSL](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/bulletinjan2017-3431551.html), so if contacting support is an option, it might be preferable.